# c# Set SQL-query result into chart

Tags: c#, sql, charts

I'm new with C# so this can be a stupid question but google didn't help me.

I've created a new project (SharePoint 2016 Empty Project and then added a Visual Web Part) in Visual Studio and in my ascx-file i've created an empty chart "ChartExample".

In my ascx.cs-file I have a query where I'm getting the information from a SQL-server. I can use this information for a gridview but how can I set this data into my chart?

I've tried a lot of things but always getting errors.

This is the current code I have (without code to add content to my chart)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=***;database=***;user id=***;password=***");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select column1 , column2 from dbo.myTable";
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.Open();
da.Fill(ds);
//Working code for GridView
GridView.DataSource = ds;
GridView.DataBind();

conn.Close();
```

So how can I add the same result into a chart?

This is the code in my ascx file:

```
<asp:Chart ID="ChartExample" runat="server">
   <Series>
       <asp:Series Name="Example"></asp:Series>
   </Series>
   <ChartAreas>
       <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartExample"></asp:ChartArea>
   </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: What technology are you using to create your chart?

Comment: This only shows how you retrieve the data. What did you try or search for yourself before posting? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PeterSmith I'm writing the code in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @RobIII Tried a lot of things like converting to list, using SQLDataReader and DataBindTable, ... But I think never the right way. The problem is that I never found an example with a SQL-query or DataSet

Comment: @endeka I understand, but converting to list, SQLDataReader etc. doesn't have ANYTHING to do with creating a chart so it's totally irrelevant. What did you try to solve your **problem**? What attempts did you make? What searches with keywords did you use? What have you done towards trying to create the chart? Have you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @endeka you have chart libraries like Chart.js (for example) that have tutorials that can help you.

Comment: Chart has many ways of data-binding. Recommended: You can __data-bind__ the `Points` of a MSChart `Series` to a `DataTable`. Many examples around..

Comment: You want a sample that binds data from DataTable?

Comment: @Tomato32 I start with my query and DataSet and at the end I have my chart but I don't know how I can connect both so my chart shows some information from my query

Comment: @endeka: You can visit this link: http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/ASPDotNet/create-chart-in-asp-application.aspx?Id=108 to refer more. Hope to help, my friend :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=***;database=***;user id=***;password=***");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select column1 , column2 from dbo.myTable";
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

conn.Open();
da.Fill(ds);
this.ChartExample.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

//Mapping a field with x-value of chart
this.ChartExample.Series[0].XValueMember = "column1";

//Mapping a field with y-value of Chart
this.ChartExample.Series[0].YValueMembers = "column2";

//Bind the DataTable with Chart
this.ChartExample.DataBind();

conn.Close();
```